# Error: Updating profiles from origin git in Grails

Tags: git, grails

I have just installed Grails through [SDKman](http://sdkman.io/) but when I tried to create an app occurred the following errors:

**| Error** Problem updating profiles from origin git repository (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

**| Error** Could not checkout tag for Grails release [3.0.9]: Ref v3.0.9 can not be resolved (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

**| Error** Cannot find profile web

Using --stacktrace:

**| Error** Problem updating profiles from origin git repository
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: https://github.com/grails/grails-profile-repository: **cannot open git-upload-pack**
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:139)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.git.GitProfileRepository.fetchAndRebaseIfExpired(GitProfileRepository.groovy:140)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.git.GitProfileRepository.createOrUpdateRepository(GitProfileRepository.groovy:109)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.git.GitProfileRepository.getProfile(GitProfileRepository.groovy:56)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.CreateAppCommand.handle(CreateAppCommand.groovy:70) ...

Running **grails -version** I have:

**| Grails Version: 3.0.9**

**| Groovy Version: 2.4.5**

**| JVM Version: 1.7.0_85**

*OBS: I don't know my proxy number and port.*

Thanks for your time!!!

Comment: Does it work from the command line? Not sure eclipse works with grails 3

Comment: The error is from the command line. I have another computer with grails 3.0.9 and it works perfectly through command line. I have never tried grails with Eclipse, I usually use Atom.

Comment: Ahhh, sorry you tagged this as eclipse